# Append Text Insert to ListBox or ComboBox1

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox, listbox

I have a richTextBox1 with this line:

```
my test
my test2
```

and tried to use this code to insert the lines in to a listbox or combox:

```
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"New ID.txt").ToString();
listBox1.Items.Add(richTextBox1.Text);
```

but the listbox displays

> mytestmytest2

How do I insert (append) each item as a new line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should split the text coming from richTextBox1 based on line feeds. If you want multiple items in your listbox, you should call Items.Add for each item.

Example:

```
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"New ID.txt").ToString(); 

foreach (string line in richTextBox.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(line); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"New ID.txt").ToString();
listBox1.Items.AddRange(richTextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
```

You dont need a loop in insert all the items. this can be done by using Items.AddRange

Answer (score 1):

To add a string one after one, use `File.ReadAllLines()` method.

```
string []lines=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");

    foreach(string str in lines)
     {
      listBox1.Items.Add(str);
     }
```

Another way to draw text is to set `DrawMode=OwnerDrawVariable` and handle the [DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawmode.aspx) event to draw the text.